# Loop nested arrays with pixel data to one array

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, pixel

[image: Updated image]

In here example we have arrays matrix 2*2 but it could be any e.g. 4x4, 16x16.

e.g.: we go through first array line 1 and then we go through second array line 1. After we come to the end of array's 2 last items we jump to the third array and so on. We know that every array (image parts) contains 64 columns/rows (pixels), so for 128px image we loop 2 arrays through and then move bottom ones.

What is the formula for looping through arrays in this kind of scenarios?

Here is something that I trying to do, but not work...

```
# e.g. we have final image 128x128, so we have parts 4 * 64x64

# Empty arrays for every pixel
final_image_pixels = [None] * part_pixel_count * total_parts_count

# Loop through every parts
for i in range(len(image_pixels)):
    for x in range(part_width):                  
        for y in range(part_height):
            # Get location on part
            px_part_index = x + y * part_width
            # Index on final array
            px_final_index = px_part_index + (i * part_pixel_count)
            final_image_pixels[px_final_index] = image_pixels[i][px_part_index]
```

**Result Now:**
(These colors do not relate to description image above)

[image]

**Should be:**

[image]

Comment: So u r also removing duplicate values while ordering considering your output?

Comment: @Marcos No there are no duplicate values. Only one array per pixel. So I do not want to remove possible duplicate values. If you thinking about that Image, numbers are presenting more like index values.

Comment: Why do you want the result to be a list of one-entry lists, rather than just a simple list of numbers?

Comment: From your question: "to this `[ [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]... ]`" Surely for those inputs you actually want `[ [1],[2],[3],[1],[2],... ]`?

Comment: @JimOldfield Updated post and trying to explain what I meant. Hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to combine image parts together with looping nested arrays. Although the script itself is not the most beautiful... I mark this answer to correct now, but if somebody is doing better that works in this context, I'll change it.

So here is "monster" that I've used in this case:

```
final_image_pixels = []
for i in range(parts_count, 0, -1):
    for row in range(part_height):    
        part_switch = -1           
        px_counter = -1            
        for col in range(final_image_width):
            if col % part_width == 0:
                part_switch += 1
                px_counter = 0
            if i-1 == 0:
                px_arr = i-1 + part_switch
            else:
                px_arr = ((i-1) * parts_count) + part_switch
            target_pixel = row * part_width + px_counter
            final_image_pixels.append(part_pixels[px_arr][target_pixel])
            px_counter += 1
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

If you want to investigate more about where I use this loop [check here](https://github.com/Creatide/RenderFarts/blob/ea3c4a59c90527561092e4f50e1f77b551e2a093/src/__init__.py#L177). This is part of [RenderFart blender addon](https://github.com/Creatide/RenderFarts).

Answer (score 0):

you can make this list flat first and then sort it

```
import itertools 
a = [ [[1],[2],[3]], [[1],[2],[3]], [[1],[2],[3]], [[1],[2],[3]] ]

b = list(itertools.chain(*a)) 
print(sorted(b))
```

The output of above code is:

```
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [2], [2], [2], [2], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
```

If you do not want to sort then you can just use

```
print(list(itertools.chain(*a)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Sorting doesn't work in this case. It will sort every array while we need those in a specific order. I updated the description, so maybe it's more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to iterate over array indices and then index into the arrays, why not iterate over them directly?

```
vals = [ [[1],[2],[3]], [[1],[2],[3]], [[1],[2],[3]], [[1],[2],[3]] ]
result = []
for nested in vals:  # e.g. nested = [[1], [2], [3]]
    for more_nested in nested:  # e.g. more_nested = [1]
        val = more_nested[0]  # e.g. val = 1
        result.append([val])
```

After running this, `result` contains:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3]]
```

If it's not necessary to make *new* one-entry lists in the output array, you can simplify the last two lines:

```
result.append(more_nested)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It seems you flatten array while it's not work in this case. I may have poorly described this question, so I updated the image and description.